# Debugging Firefox Addon IDE

Tags: javascript, ide, firefox-addon, aptana, firefox-addon-sdk

I find myself developing a Firefox Addon with the `ADD-ON SDK`.

Is it possible to debug this extension with an IDE, like Aptana or WebStorm?

This extension modifies a Web Page Based on URL, and should have several content scripts.

Using the `page-mod` module, and believe also the `self module` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to debug SDK code remotely, however we would love to eventually be able to hook into Firefox's new JS debugger ( now available in Firefox 15 beta ).

Answer (score 3):

Currenly the only way is using error console (Ctrl+Shift+J).